# Why are there 2 identical class options for Visual C# in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, class, templates, visual-studio-2015

I have seen this before when working in Visual Studio and always wondered why. I could not find any explanation online.

In Visual Studio Professional 2015 (May be the case in other versions but I have not tested) when adding a new class to a project

> Right click project --> Add --> class -

I see 2 seemingly identical options for Visual C# classes. The description of these are exactly the same. I have tried adding both and can not find any difference in the 2.

Is this a bug? Or does anybody know why I see 2 different Class options?

[image: vs class]

Comment: @DerreckDean Helpful comment....

Comment: I only have one item in VS2015. Maybe you downloaded some online templates that caused duplicates?

Comment: You probably have multiple templates in your VS folder.

Comment: Your VS2015 install is corrupted, pretty common issue.  If that is the only problem you have then count your blessings.

Comment: That would be my guess, it's happened to me before with V2012.

Comment: @HansPassant  I have tried restarting VS multiple times to see if it was a glitch. Even restarted my PC. It happens no matter what Project type I choose under C#. Have not looked to other project types to see if it affects everything.

Comment: So you guys think I should just keep coding on and not worry about it?

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx). Those items you see are *templates*, somewhere you have a duplicate.

Comment: @Sinatr how could I find out where this template is? I don't see anything under C:\Users\alex.chance\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have one item in **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition**

One possibility is that you downloaded additional templates, which caused duplicates. Or you could have corrupted your installation somehow.

**To answer your question** - why there are two items: There shouldn't be! And usually there aren't. If you re-install Visual Studio completely, it should be fixed, but I wouldn't go that far just to fix this minor issue.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yeah, not sure if I want to reinstall VS. I don't recall downloading any templates, but guess it's possible.

Comment: I also definitely don't suggest re-installing VS just because of this. You should just ignore minor issues like these, they come along often.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I will just keep on working and not worry about it unless something else blows up - which I'm sure is bound to happen eventually.